# changing alpha value in SDL_SetRenderDrawColor doesn't effect anything. SDL2

Tags: sdl-2

This code shows just a simple window with a color:

```
#include<SDL.h>                     
SDL_Window* g_pWindow = 0;
SDL_Renderer* g_pRenderer = 0;
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) >= 0)
    {
        g_pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Chapter 1: Setting up SDL",
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
            640, 480,
            SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if (g_pWindow != 0)
        {
            g_pRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(g_pWindow, -1, 0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 1; // sdl could not initialize
    }
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(g_pRenderer, 80, 80, 253, 0);
    // clear the window to black
    SDL_RenderClear(g_pRenderer);
    // show the window
    SDL_RenderPresent(g_pRenderer);
    // set a delay before quitting
    SDL_Delay(2000);
    // clean up SDL
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm testing to see what happens when I change the alpha factor in `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(g_pRenderer, 80, 80, 253, 0)`. When I change the alpha value from 0 to 255 it doesn't effect anything.

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you haven't enabled blending (e.g. `SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);`).

But anyway, it makes no sense for `clear` operation to use blending, and I bet `SDL_RenderClear` ignores it.

If you want fullscreen blend, you should draw fullscreen rectangle with `SDL_RenderFillRect`.

Answer (score 0):

Writing this line will make alpha values have effect on transparency:

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
```

**No need to rewrite** every time & for every effert, just write once before using transparency

see documentation on more blend modes:
https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_BlendMode